AWS Quicksight BigQuery dataset token expires: `Your Salesforce oauth token has expired, login again in the pop-up. ...`
I have several Quicksight datasets connected to BigQuery that were running just fine for a number of days. I came back after a couple weeks to find that all queries to this dataset are failing to refresh their authentication. When I go in to edit the dataset I get this error message: Your Salesforce oauth token has expired, login again in the pop-up. If you do not find the pop-up, allow pop-ups in your browser and refresh page.
Don't ask me why it's telling me about Salesforce. This has nothing to do with Salesforce.
I enabled popups and refreshed the page, but it didn't do anything. I'm not paying for a premium AWS account so I can't submit a support ticket.

